# SqlException: The multi-part identifier "chamin@gmail.com" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mssql-jdbc

When i try to execute the query in given bellow

[image]

is worked correctly and give the result

[image]

but when i change id into email then it will raise the exception

```cs
    employee = connection.Query<Employee>("select id, email as email , password as password, role as role from Employee where email="+"chamin@gmail.com");
```

[image]

how do i fix this problem??

Comment: Use [parameterized queries](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/). That will address this problem and avoid many others.

Answer (score 0):

Strings have to be quoted in SQL :

```
employee = connection.Query<Employee>(
"select id, email as email , password as password, role as role from Employee where email='"+"chamin@gmail.com" + "'"
);
```

But your code is very permissive to SQL injection. You should use SQL parameters : it will prevent injection and avoid the issue you met.

Comment: The code in question looks to be using the SqlClient API so it supports proper parameters.

Comment: I saw it and I edited my answer in this way. But I had not heard of a ```Query``` method on the ```SqlConnection``` class

Comment: Didn't notice the `Query` method. If this is some sort of wrapper, hopefully it supports methods to use parameters with `SqlClient`.